# Nested ForEach loop to Linq

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, linq-to-entities, nested-loops

I am trying to convert below nested for each loop into Linq. However I am still unable to do it successfully.

```
var objAct = new List<InformaticsBenchmarkSummary>();
foreach (var item in op)
{
    foreach (var lstTp5 in lstTopFive)
    {
        if (item.UnitOfOperations.ContainsKey(lstTp5.SystemID))
        {
            var objIbm = new InformaticsBenchmarkSummary();
            objIbm.CompanyId = item.CompanyId;
            objIbm.CompanyName = item.CompanyName;
            objIbm.LocationId = item.LocationId;
            objIbm.LocationName = item.LocationName;
            objIbm.UnitOfOperations.Add(lstTp5.SystemID, 
                                        item.UnitOfOperations[lstTp5.SystemID]);
            objAct.Add(objIbm);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `UnitOfOperations` is of type `Dictionary<int,string>()`;
`op` is again `List<InformaticsBenchmarkSummary>()`
`lstTopFive` is `List<int>()`

I tried, something like this but was unsuccessful syntactically

```
var output = from item in op
from lstTp5 in lstTopFive
where item.UnitOfOperations.ContainsKey(lstTp5.SystemID)
let v = new InformaticsBenchmarkSummary()
{
     CompanyId = item.CompanyId,
     CompanyName = item.CompanyName,
     LocationId = item.LocationId,
     LocationName = item.LocationName
}
.UnitOfOperations.Add(lstTp5.SystemID, item.UnitOfOperations[lstTp5.SystemID])
select v;
```

Nested loop works perfectly but I think, linq on this will increase performance.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: ReSharper can do this for you. You can download a 30 day evaluation if you're not keen to purchase it.

Comment: Most of the time, LINQ won't increase performance, it has to do all the same looping you're doing now.

Comment: @levelnis It often can, but in this specific case, even ReSharper can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible in a Linq query-syntax to use the `UnitOfOperations.Add` in the select. But you can do it using Method Chain and a `SelectMany` method:

```
var objAcu = (op.SelectMany(item => lstTopFive, (item, lstTp5) => new { item, lstTp5 })  // <- Bad readability
                .Where(t => t.item.UnitOfOperations.ContainsKey(t.lstTp5.SystemID))
                .Select(t =>
                        {
                            var objIbm = new InformaticsBenchmarkSummary
                            {
                                CompanyId = t.item.CompanyId,
                                CompanyName = t.item.CompanyName,
                                LocationId = t.item.LocationId,
                                LocationName = t.item.LocationName
                            };
                            objIbm.UnitOfOperations.Add(t.lstTp5.SystemID, t.item.UnitOfOperations[t.lstTp5.SystemID]);
                            return objIbm;
                        })).ToList();
```

If the property `UnitOfOperations` has a public `set`, in this case, you can use the query-syntax.

How do you replace 1 `foreach`? By a `from ... in ...`

Then, to replace 2 `foreach`, use 2 `from ... in ...`

```
var objAct = (from item in op  // First foreach loop
              from lstTp5 in lstTopFive  // Second foreach loop
              where item.UnitOfOperations.ContainsKey(lstTp5.SystemID)
              select new InformaticsBenchmarkSummary
              {
                  CompanyId = item.CompanyId,
                  CompanyName = item.CompanyName,
                  LocationId = item.LocationId,
                  LocationName = item.LocationName,
                  UnitOfOperations = { { lstTp5.SystemID, item.UnitOfOperations[lstTp5.SystemID] } }
              }).ToList();
```

But I doubt it will increase performance in such an operation.

Anyway, I don't understand what you try to achieve. Because in all items of the output will have one and only one element in the dictionary `UnitOfOperations`. Is it really what you want to do?

#### UPDATE

```
List<int> systemIdTop5 = lstTopFive.Select(tp5 => tp5.SystemID).ToList();
var objAct = (from item in op
              select new InformaticsBenchmarkSummary
              {
                  CompanyId = item.CompanyId,
                  CompanyName = item.CompanyName,
                  LocationId = item.LocationId,
                  LocationName = item.LocationName,
                  UnitOfOperations = systemIdTop5.Intersect(item.UnitOfOperations.Keys)
                                                 .ToDictionary(systemId => systemId, systemId => item.UnitOfOperations[systemId])
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Cedric for your reply.

Yes, your understanding is right. I am trying to fetch all the UnitOfOperations which have respective key in lstTopFive.

UnitOfOperations dictionary has many elements but I want to select few of them, however keeping other CompanyId, LocationId and names as is..

Comment: It's not impossible, there is a syntax exactly for that, see my answer.

Comment: @SagarS. I've updated my answer to return a new list of _InformaticsBenchmarkSummary_ with the _UnitOfOperations_ filtered to get only _UnitOfOperation_ that are defined in _lstTopFive_.

Comment: @CédricBignon Thank you Cedric. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @SagarS. Can I understand why you have accepted the answer from svick? Given that I've written exactly the same code 15 minutes before.

Comment: @CédricBignon Both of you have given the answers what I needed. However, when I clicked 'Older' tab (under active,older & votes) section, it shows that answer first.
I would rather prefer selecting two answers at a time. Yours & his if it allows

Comment: @SagarS. That's right. Maybe the _Oldest_ tab take the last edit into account. Usually I look at the "answered ... ago" at the bottom of each answer.

Comment: @CédricBignon I agree. Sorry, I didn't notice that first.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you can't just use a `void` returning method in LINQ query like that. (And if it wasn't `void`-returning, then `v` would be the result of `Add()`, which would be most likely wrong.)

If you wanted to create a new `Dictionary` for `UnitOfOperations`, you could set it the same way as other properties. But if you can't do that (probably because `UnitOfOperations` has a private setter) or you don't want to (because `UnitOfOperations` is initialized to some value that you want to keep), you can use a lesser known feature of C#: collection initializer inside object initializer:

```
UnitOfOperations = { { lstTp5.SystemID, item.UnitOfOperations[lstTp5.SystemID] } }
```

The effect of this code is the same as if you wrote:

```
createdObject.UnitOfOperations.Add(lstTp5.SystemID, item.UnitOfOperations[lstTp5.SystemID]);
```

The only difference is that it's not a statement, it's part of an expression, which means you can use it in a LINQ query.

The whole query would then be:

```
var output = from item in op
             from lstTp5 in lstTopFive
             where item.UnitOfOperations.ContainsKey(lstTp5.SystemID)
             select new InformaticsBenchmarkSummary()
             {
                 CompanyId = item.CompanyId,
                 CompanyName = item.CompanyName,
                 LocationId = item.LocationId,
                 LocationName = item.LocationName,
                 UnitOfOperations =
                 {
                     { lstTp5.SystemID, item.UnitOfOperations[lstTp5.SystemID] }
                 }
             };
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's where I was stuck at and you pointed me right direction.
Since, UnitOfOperation is already initialized in constructor; your solution works for me

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell it is your UnitOfOperations that you're having difficulty with. If it is initialized in the constructor you can use this:

```
            var output = from item in op
                     from lstTp5 in lstTopFive
                     where item.UnitOfOperations.ContainsKey(lstTp5.SystemID)
                     select
                         new InformaticsBenchmarkSummary()
                             {
                                 CompanyId = item.CompanyId,
                                 CompanyName = item.CompanyName,
                                 LocationId = item.LocationId,
                                 LocationName = item.LocationName,
                                 UnitOfOperations = { { lstTp5.SystemID, item.UnitOfOperations[lstTp5.SystemID] } }
                             };
```

The result is an `IEnumerable`, if you want it as a list, call `output.ToList()`.

Two side notes:

1. I don't believe this will be any quicker. It is still a inner loop.
2. This might produce almost duplicate items in the result (different `UnitOfOperations`), but I guess that is desired. In the worst case scenario all items in `op` have a `UnitOfOperations` that contain all the `SystemID` in `lstTopFive` giving us a total of `op.Count()*lstTopFive.Count()` items in the `output`.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. I am definitely going to think over it as nested foreach has more readability than linq if performance is not going to increase

Answer (score 0):

May this help U :

```
var output = from item in op
                 join lstTp5 in lstTopFive on item.UnitOfOperations.Key equals lstTp5.SystemID
                 select new InformaticsBenchmarkSummary
                 {
                     CompanyId = item.CompanyId,
                     CompanyName = item.CompanyName,
                     LocationId = item.LocationId,
                     LocationName = item.LocationName,
                     UnitOfOperations = item.UnitOfOperations 
                 };
```